# Algorithm which finds the last digit of raising to a power every previous digit into the current

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm

I've been trying to implement the algorithm which does raising to a power every previous digit to current digit, which is also raised to. Then I find the last digit of this number. Here is the formula of this algorithm:

```
(x0 ** (x1 ** (x2 ** (x3 ** (...) **(Xn))))))
```

Then I find the last digit like that:

```
return find_last_digit % 10
```

If the list is empty, programm must return 1.
I have the Solution of this problem:

```
def last_digit(lst):
    if len(lst) > 0:
        temp = lst[-1]
        for i in range(len(lst) - 2, -1, -1):
            temp = lst[i] ** temp
        return temp % 10
    else:
        return 1
```

But as you can see, this code takes a lot of time to be implemented if any value of the input list is large. Could you answer me, how can I make this code more effecient? Thx a lot

Comment: Are you trying to impliment the [`tetration operator`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration)? if so, note that there is a limit to the value you can compute. eg `2**(2**(2**(2**2)))` is a very huge number. If you add an extra 2 the equation might even take forever to solve. So use a small list eg only 4 numbers and see whether your function works

Comment: Why did you call that `last_digit`?

Comment: @onyambu Isn't tetration just for when all numbers are equal (in which case they wouldn't use a list but just two numbers)?

Comment: @KellyBundy this Is the part of the task I want to do. Sry, my fault I haven`t renamed It

Comment: Note that the problem is not the code but rather the magnitude/size of the numbers you are dealing with here. These are huge numbers. I mean huge huge numbers. VERY VERY HUGE. For example `2**(2**(2**(2**(2**2))))` which is just a list of 6 numbers and all of them just 2 will make our computer hung! Try it out hahaha

Comment: @KellyBundy yes, but my comment is focusing on the fact that the resulting numbers are so huge that the computer cannot ksolve them.

Comment: @onyambu This code works with small list, but when I try to solve, for example list[9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9], by that code, It takes too much time, so I`m finding for ways make that code more effecient

Comment: See https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: The problem is not the code. There is no efficiency here. It's just the computer cannot solve the problem. Read my other comments. Try for example  `2**2**2**2**2**2**2` even without the code, your computer cannot solve this

Comment: @KellyBundy seems like youre kidding, but thanks. Anyways I`ve been solving It for 2 days

Comment: I'm not kidding. Show us your X and maybe we can help you.

Comment: @KellyBundy I can show It to you, but I don`t need it, because of solving this problem too long, I got interested in solving the part of the problem I have described in my question

Comment: how long does the code take to solve `lst = [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]`? This is a huge number. Why on earth would you compute this number???

Comment: @onyambu Can you explain what are you asking for?

Comment: Why do you want to compute `9**9**9**9**9**9`? Where/How will you use it? Your computer cannot even compute `2**2**2**2**2**2**2`

Comment: @onyambu My computer cant even compute your example with my code, thats why Im asking for more effecient solving of this problem to be possible to compute at least that. Dont understand how can your questions help me with solving that problem, but I have the task to implement the algorithm which is possible to solve that problem. Hope you don`t have any questions about why do I want this

Comment: Your computer cannot compute the example i gave literally. I do not mean by using your code. I mean if you type in `2**2**2**2**2**2**2` into the console WITHOUT USING YOUR CODE, your computer cannot solve it.

Comment: @onyambu Likely they're trying to do [this](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5518a860a73e708c0a000027/train/python), but clearly they don't actually want our help.

Comment: The number you asked is beyond the capacity of ordinary PC at present, so the answer is that there is no way. The question does not come from whether your code is efficient enough.

Comment: Now read https://xyproblem.info/ again and see how perfectly it describes our situation.

Comment: @MechanicPig Oh, ok, now I understand. I just exampled that and didnt even think about how large is it for the computer

Comment: @KellyBundy ok, sry, i will edit it

Comment: The issue is not the code. There is no efficient code. The issue is the algorithm. This is not the way to solve the given problem. You are in the wrong path. Think of the problem in a different way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some observations that can make the calculations more efficient:

- As we need the last digit, and we are essentially doing multiplications, we can use the rules of modular arithmetic. If ⋅ = , then (mod )⋅(mod ) = (mod ). So a first idea could be to take  as 10, and perform the multiplications. But we don't want to split up exponentiation in individual mutliplications, so then see the next point:
- For all unsigned integers  it holds that <sup>2</sup> = <sup>6</sup> modulo 20. You can verify this by doing this for all values of  in the range {0,...,19}. By consequence,  = <sup>+4</sup> for  > 1. We choose 20 as modulus as that is both a multiple of 10 and 4. A multiple of 10, because we need to maintain the last digit in the process, and 4 as we will reduce the exponent by a multiple of 4. Both are necessary conditions at the same time, so not to lose out on the final digit. In the end we have that (mod 20)(mod 10) = (mod 10)

With these simplification rules, you can keep the involved exponents limited to at most 5, the base to at most 21, and the resulting power to at most 21<sup>5</sup> = 4084101.

The code could become:

```
def last_digit(lst):
    power = 1
    for base in reversed(lst):
        power = (base if base < 2 else (base - 2) % 20 + 2) ** (
                     power if power < 2 else (power - 2) % 4 + 2)
    return power % 10
```

In practice you can skip the reduction of `base` to `(base - 2) % 20 + 2` if these input numbers are not very large.

Comment: Ok, also passes [my tests](https://tio.run/##XVDNasMwDL77KbRDwcl8aNcOymieZIzhJkpncG0jK/t5@sxxxAjzTfp@5fTDHzEcz4nmeaR4B8dIHKPP4O4pEkOiOEw9KzXgCN5mfh/czbH2mZsXBeWl@IUEHRzqNEaCq80ILgDhJ1LGYUPeCiqtbUGvCzcKcoEnQF@wddzBCR7h1FQ9IU8U/pDDXqkl0Rq4GuiXUCmsyYYb6ud9Y4oooeXuKB3wO2HPpUBx0YuybXtTrNaE0rVAr@L4Jql58sv63wdUsPQW/KET782t5ELlGoGMkJt5/gU) with `product(range(50), repeat=3)`, where your original failed 16440 cases (13%). I'll still need to think it through thoroughly to be fully convinced, but seems good now :-)

Comment: Two things still irritate me: 1) You don't seem to use the first of your two observations. 2) Your second observation discusses examples like 117649 with last digit 9, using base 10. But your solution doesn't actually use base 10, except to mod the final result. During the whole calculation, you're rather using base 4 instead. And last digit in base 4 and base 10 is not the same.

Comment: @Kelly, yes this was not very clear. I completely rewrote those two points, and introduced a modular operation on the base-number as well (not needed to pass the codewars tests, but still interesting to keep the magnitudes down).